# create a new column named as group_ID in pandas, if the first 2 characters of name are same and DOB is same or missing it must fall in same Group ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

create a new column named as `group_ID` in pandas, if the first 2 characters of `fname` and `last_name` are same and `DOB` is same or missing it must fall in same Group ID

[image]

```
Fname   Lname       dob        GID
PNRM     ATPN      14-01-1950   1
PNRM     ATPN                   1
PNRM     ATPN                   1
SMO      XTS       14-06-2001   2
SMO      XTS                    2
```

I have tried the following code

```
df['GID'] = df.groupby([df['fname'].str[:2], df['last_name'].str[:2], 'dob'] or [df['fname'].str[:2], df['last_name'].str[:2], df['dob'].isnull()]).ngroup()
```

The problem with the above code is it is assigning Nan if `DOB` is missing

Comment: need help urgently

Answer (score 0):

If your `dob` column is consecutive, you can try to forward fill the `dob` column

```py
df['GID'] = df.groupby([df['fname'].str[:2], df['last_name'].str[:2], df['dob'].ffill()]).ngroup()
```